# Create a lambda function that allows me to identify if a regex capturing group is equal to another capturing group, and if so replace it

Tags: python, regex, lambda

```py
import re

input_text = "Asegurarse que halla 4(4) o 5( 5  ) de ellos, también 24(24 48), o sino 24, (24 )no 66(70 y seis), o () 56(), 56(5 6) ssd 56"

lambda_fuction_result = lambda m: re.sub(r"", "", m.group())

input_text = re.sub(capture_groups_with_regex, lambda_fuction_result, input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

The **correct output** that I need obtain:

```
"Asegurarse que halla 4 o 5 de ellos, también 24(24 48), o sino 24, (24 )no 66(70 y seis), o () 56(), 56(5 6) ssd 56"
```

I need the data that is entered repeated between parentheses to be removed from the main string, since they are redundant clarifications. These replacements should only be done if the parentheses are immediately after the number, and that the number inside the parentheses is exactly equal to the number that is before them, you must also consider that the number inside the parentheses must be alone and there must be nothing more inside them.

The regex should look something like this `r"\d*[\s|]([\s|]*\d*[\s|]*)[\s|]"`, , but that it has some validation that allows me to evaluate that the `\d*` in front of the parentheses is equal to the `\d*` inside the parentheses

Comment: why must this be a lambda expresssion? Note, following standard style conventions (PEP 8) then this should have been a regular function definition statement

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if it is possible, it would be better with a lambda expression but if it is too complicated it could be done with a normal function

Comment: Actually, I can't find any difference between input and desired output.

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez, is this what you want? `re.sub(r"(\d+)\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)", lambda m: m[m[1] == m[2]], input_text)`

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez **why would it be better**? What *advantage* do you think the lambda expression gives you? Again, in your code, if following proper style guidelines, you should have either used a function definition statement or not assigned the result of the lambda expression to a variable

Comment: What juanpa said. A lambda expression is for creating a simple anonymous function. If you want a named function, use `def`. That gives you a function with a useful `.__name__` attribute, rather than "<lambda>".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood your task is to remove parentheses with number if it equals number before those parentheses.

First of all you need a regular expression which matches number and number in parentheses in separate capturing groups:

```
(\d+)\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)
```

*Link to [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jkrnNZ/1).*

To check whether values of both capturing groups are equal we can exploit feature of [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and pass a function to second argument which will compare groups and return either number or full match.

```py
def replace(match):
    if match.group(1) == match.group(2):
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        return match.group(0)  # keep same

input_text = "this 0(   0) is 0 (1   ) test 100    ( 1 0 0   ) string 1(1)."
result = re.sub(r"(\d+)\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)", replace, input_text)
```

Let's shorten our function. It's quite more compact to access capturing groups using indexing *(e.g. `match[0]`)*. Also we can apply some *python magic*. In python `True` equals `1` and `False` equals `0` and *(as you might have noticed)* our `replace()` function returns either group `0` or group `1`. Combining all this together we can use condition itself as index of group:

```py
def replace(match):
    return match.group(match.group(1) == match.group(2))
# OR
def replace(match):
    return match[match[1] == match[2]]
# OR
replace = lambda m: m[m[1] == m[2]]
```

Shortened version of code:

```py
input_text = "this 0(   0) is 0 (1   ) test 100    ( 1 0 0   ) string 1(1)."
result = re.sub(r"(\d+)\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)", lambda m: m[m[1] == m[2]], input_text)
```

Output:

```
this 0 is 0 (1   ) test 100    ( 1 0 0   ) string 1.
```

---

**Upd.** I completely forgot about *backreferences* when wrote this answer.

There's a better way to implement this:

```py
input_text = "this 0(   0) is 0 (1   ) test 100    ( 1 0 0   ) string 1(1)."
result = re.sub(r"(\d+)\s*\(\s*\1\s*\)", r"\1", input_text)
```

Here using `\1` we let regular expressions engine to do all the job matching only equal numbers. Link to [*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/jkrnNZ/2).